# using BCP to fill a column of a table with a single value

Tags: sql-server, powershell, bcp

Let's say I have a table with 5 columns, some data with 4 columns, and a format file that specifies where bcp should write that 4-column data (obviously one column will be unused).

Is there any way to use bcp to supply a single value for that 5th column at the time bcp is executed? That is, when I run BCP, I want 4 of the columns in the table to be filled with my data, and I want the 5th column to be filled with a single integer. I'm guessing no, but it would be insanely helpful if it could be done.

EDIT: The problem with using a separate query to fill this column is that there are millions of records. It times out once the table gets big enough. I know that there is a default value concept in bcp, but here's the rub: the default value will vary depending on the Excel file I'm currently blasting in. Perhaps I can change the default value each time?

Comment: How about increasing or removing altogether the timeout? Sql Server doesn't have any kind of timeout for "too long" queries, it's the client that times out.

Comment: I tried that. For some reason, it didn't work. I'm not sure why, but I figured I'd just go in a totally new direction and try to bypass having to make the query.

Comment: what if you don't BCP that one column in and just set a default value for it in SQL?   You'd have to change it for each file but you can do that programmatically.  Or just fake the value, "XXXX" and after you BCP update that column to whatever the default is?

Comment: @sniperd I think that's what I'm probably going to do. Can't think of any other way.

Comment: @KingHenryV cool, I write up a proper answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two ways I can think of doing is are

- Don't BCP that one column in and just set a default value for it in SQL.  You'd have to change it for each file but you can do that programmatically.
- Use a fake the value in the file you are using to BCP in like "XXXX".  After you BCP the data in simply run an update on that column

Good luck!

Comment: I'm good on your first bullet point, but not your second. Why is it necessary to fake the value? Also, I'm not totally clear on what you mean by "faking it"?

Comment: Oh, sorry.  Instead of omitting a column in the file and using the DEFAULT value in the SQL column, put in a column with static data like 'XXXXXX' or '1' or whatever.  And then after the import to SQL, just run `UPDATE table SET col1 = 'the value you want'`

Comment: Well, here's the thing: I'm trying to get around having to modify the data files.

Comment: oh never mind: that's just one option. The first way (what I'm trying) doesn't require editing it.